# Varnish FPC Cache Warmer

Tags: batch-file, caching, magento2, varnish

I've a working batch file cache warmer, but as you might notice, it's only warming up the cache for not logged in users.
How can I be sure that it warms up the cache for all the users? Should I login into different types of accounts and warmup the cache or is there another way?

```
@echo off
chcp 1252
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "loc="
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in (
        'find /i "<Loc>" ^< "sitemap.xml"'
    ) do ( set "loc=%%a"
        curl %%a > nul
        echo %%a
        ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 2000 > nul
    )

    pause
```

Comment: I think you won't have many gains trying to warm up logged in users. If there is a cacheable ESI block for a user session, it is likely also present in a guest session. Furthermore, a user session will have many specific user blocks that are either very low TTL or are uncacheable.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin The problem is that only logged in users can see some of the page information, for example, prices and product options. And the prices are different for each customer group